# How to make SingleChildScrollView fill full screen height with blank space where required

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my flutter app I need a layout where I'm able to scroll if all the widgets are too long for the screen,so I added a SingleChildScrollView. But, if the widgets are smaller and leave a lot of space, I want the last row to be pinned to the bottom of the screen with blank space between the last two items. So I added a Spacer to help with that.

However that causes an error, because the SingleChildScrollView doesn't like the Spacer. I've tried everything I know, but I can't find a layout that satisfies both conditions without an error. Can someone suggest a solution please?

Code below - you may have to alter the size (or number) of the containers to demonstrate the issue on your device.

```
class _TestMain extends State<TestMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                // comment out these four containers to demonstrate issue
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                // SingleChildScrollView won't allow the Spacer
                //const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text("I'm always fixed to the bottom of the screen!"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error if I add the Spacer is:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
```

Comment: Avoid pasting code-image, provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What do you mean with _SingleChildScrollView doesn't like the Spacer_? What error does it return?

Comment: question edited with error...

Comment: You can create a separate widget and include on question that will reproduce the same issue instead of code-image.

Comment: Added code instead of image, I'll remember next time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `CustomScrollView` and `SliverFillRemaining` to achieve what you want.

This way we can also use `Spacer` and `Expanded` widgets inside the scrollable list:

```dart
        Scaffold(
              body: SafeArea(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverFillRemaining(
                      hasScrollBody: false,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text("I'm at top part"),
                          Text("I'm at top part"),
                          Text("I'm at top part"),
                          const Spacer(),
                          Text("I'm at bottom"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Tried this, but when data fills everything and there's no free space, there's overflow and scrolling is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderMarochko could you share the code so that I can check what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can using set height infinity of Container contain SingleChildScrollView

```
Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            // Content
          ),
        )
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`bottomNavigationBar` from `Scaffold`.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: 100,
    child: Text("I'm always fixed to the bottom of the screen!"),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(...
```

And
You can use CustomScrollView which is better than   SingleChildScrollView; and use SliverFillRemaining will do the trick with Align widget.

```dart
class TestMain extends StatefulWidget {
  TestMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestMain> createState() => _TestMain();
}

class _TestMain extends State<TestMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 100,
        child: Text("I'm always fixed to the bottom of the screen!"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            /// your top level items
            // SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) => ,)),

            SliverList(
                // better use `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              // you can put regular container here
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ])),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text("I'm always fixed to the bottom of the screen!"),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Container(bg: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3)), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=100.0)):
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderConstrainedBox.

Comment: What you’ve put inside the sliver that providing this error

Comment: Yap, they all needed to be sliver type

Comment: Well this is better to me, else you have calculated the size of items and making scrollable will give overflow. check the link, sliver are better than anything. You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY-_yrZdjGc)

Comment: Ah, but a new problem... the top containers can now be scrolled off the top of the screen, even if only half the screen is full. I don't want scroll enabled in this case. Also, when the screen is full, they actually scroll over the bottom container.

Comment: Widget only becomes scrollable when it is not able to fit on viewport, test the snippet and see the result, changes some and you can learn something, & nothing is new forever

Comment: No, in your snippet, you can scroll the amber container off the top of the screen. And if I add lots of containers, they scroll over the bottom container.

Comment: oH Sorry I misunderstood the question,

Comment: Can you check the update answer

Comment: No sorry, you really have misunderstood the question! This is all one view, that should all scroll together. The problem is on some screens it doesn't fill the whole view height, and I want the bottom item to move to the bottom of the screen. If you run my original code and comment out where I indicated, the issue is quite obvious I would hope.

Comment: *screens it doesn't fill the whole view height, and I want the bottom item to move to the bottom of the screen.* for this case previous one was OK?